# How to Add custom data to customer session?

Tags: magento2, customer-session

In **LoginPost** controller using this **"Magento\Customer\Model\Session"** session. After Login I need to add a **custom array** to the current customer session. how can i add a custom data to magento customer session? please help me with your valuable answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create **customer_login** event observer for set value in customer session after login

**1) Create events.xml**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_login">
        <observer name="customer_login_observer" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CustomerLogin" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**2) After this file, you need to create your observer file**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/CustomerLogin.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CustomerLogin implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }   

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer(); //Get customer object
        $myArray = array('value1','value2');
        $setValye = $this->customerSession->setMyValue($myArray); //set value in customer session
        $getValue = $this->customerSession->getMyValue(); //Get value from customer session
        print_r($getValue);
        exit;
    }
}
```

**Now run this commands:**

> php bin/magento cache:flush
>
> php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: Thank you somuch For Your valuable feedback. Its helped me a lot

Comment: Yr welcome.. :)

Comment: i can't use print_r for $customer, How can i print the $customer?

Comment: You can print $customer object by __print_r($customer->getData())__ or __print_r($customer->debug())__

Comment: Yea its working..

Comment: I have one doubt. How can i use model in the above observer?

Comment: Which model you want to use?

Comment: Any Model from module-customer as like Customer.php. I tried to access a Customer.php but its not working, am stuck in this situation. Actually I need to call a model function from the above observer . Do You understand what i mean?

Comment: Simple you can construct model in constructor as I construct customer session in above answer. If you need more explaination for call model in observer. please create new question to clear this question conversation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71580/discussion-between-midlaj-and-prince-patel).

Comment: please check this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/210056/interceptor-error-in-observer?noredirect=1#comment292283_210056

Answer (score 3):

You can Set and get Customer session by using `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session`

```
protected $customerSession;

public function __construct(

    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession, 

){
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
}

$this->customerSession->setMyValue('testing');
$this->customerSession->getMyValue();
```

You can also set by objectManager , But it's wrong way :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$customerSession->setMyValue('testing value');
$customerSession->getMyValue();
```

For setting an information to the customer session :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$session = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$session->setTestKey('testing value');
```

Getting an information from the customer session:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$session = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
echo $session->getTestKey();
```

Hope this answer helpful for you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by setting any variable using  `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session` as follows:

```
protected $customerSession;

public function __construct(

    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession, 

){
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
}

$this->customerSession->setCustomValue(['anime','midlaj']);
$this->customerSession->getCustomValue();
```

Output:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'anime' (length=4)
  1 => string 'midlaj' (length=3)
```

Actually you can set and get this value across any file using same method.

Answer (score 1):

You can set custom data to customer session like below code.

```
$customArray = ['value1','value1'];
$this->session->setCustomData($customArray);
print_r($this->session->getData()); //Customer session data with custom array data
print_r($this->session->getCustomData()); //Get only custom array data.
```