# Interceptor error in Observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, interceptor

**vendor/magento/module-sales/etc/events.xml**

```
<event name="sales_order_save_after">
    <observer name="sales_order_save_after" instance="Magento\Sales\Observer\SalesOrderSaveAfter" />
</event>
```

**vendor/magento/module-sales/Observer/SalesOrderSaveAfter.php**

```
 namespace Magento\Sales\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\App\State;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderPaymentInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Payment\Collection;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as PsrLogger;




    class SalesOrderSaveAfter implements ObserverInterface
    {
        /**
        * @var $_logger
        */
        private $_logger;

        /**
        * @var \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl
        */
        protected $_curl;

    /**
     * ConvertAdditionalInfoObserver constructor.
     * @param State $state
     * @param \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl
     */
    public function __construct(
        PsrLogger $logger,
        State $state,
        \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl
    )
    {
        $this->state = $state;
        $this->_curl = $curl;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }


    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {   
        $ObserverInterface = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder(); //Get customer object

        if($ObserverInterface->getId()){
           echo $ObserverInterface->getId()."<br>";
        } 
        $OldStatus=$ObserverInterface->getOrigData('status');
        $NewStatus=$ObserverInterface->getStatus();
        echo "OldStatus: ".$OldStatus."<br>";
        echo "NewStatus: ".$NewStatus."<br>";
    }

}
```

**Output**

[image]

I am trying to get order status in sales_order_save_after observer, In the output am getting the result but it showing an interceptor error. what it means? how can i solve this issue??. Thanks in advance for your valuabe answers.

Comment: just remove var and generated folder from root

Comment: Refer [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/209309/61183) link.

Comment: i removed var/generation folder and compiled again. but it get the same error

Comment: show your full code of observer file.

Comment: i have given full observer code please check it

Comment: Try with $ObserverInterface->getEntityId()

Comment: same error shows. What Is the correct way to get order information in observer?